# Como escribir parrafo dentro de un espacio limitado

Tags: html, html5

Estoy recien aprendiendo html, me mandaron en la Universidad a hacer una página html cosa que nunca antes me habían pasado html asi que no me queda otra que aprender solo, he buscado lo más posible información pero tengo que hacerlo rápido ya que me dieron solo 7 días (sumando a que tengo otras materias que ver), asi que pido paciencia.

Tengo un párrafo y quiero ubicarlo a la derecha de la página, hasta ahí bien ya que con `<p allign="right"> </p>` se hace, pero eso no mide hasta donde llega a la izquierda el parrafo, y eso quiero evitar, porque quiero que llegué por la izquierda hasta la mitad de la página o hasta donde yo vea que me guste, y ahi no veo como hacerlo, y se que aqui hay gente experta que me saque de dudas, porque en google no encuentro lo que precisamente quiero. 
Eso sería una duda, porque tengo muchisimas, como por ejemplo, como hacer que un href quede fijo en una parte de la página sin que se mueva con imagenes que ponga, como crear un boton que redirija a otra pagina html que tenga.
Me gustaria que me ayudaran como manejar html como si escribiera en Word

Comment: No puedes pensar HTML como Word o como cualquier otro editor de texto porque **no son lo mismo**. Una gran diferencia es que lo que escribas en HTML se verá en cientos o miles de pantallas con distintos tamaños, resoluciones, etc. Así que algo que se verá a tu gusto en tu pantalla, quizá se vea horrible en la pantalla de otro. HTML trabaja con reglas CSS para ajustar tamaños, márgenes, etc y hoy se habla de los diseños *responsive*, que se adaptan a cada dispositivo. Siete días son muchos días para investigar y aprender, hay buenos manuales y tutoriales en castellano, es cuestión de buscar.

Comment: He buscado y al menos ya se hacer varias cosas, pero es primera vez que hago algo en html y como estoy contra el tiempo porque tengo otras materias que ver, necesito salir de mis dudas especificas, ya cuando haya terminado el semestre podré darle todo el tiempo a html

Comment: Entiendo, pero lo que planteas aquí no es una duda específica, es fruto de un error de comprensión. Tú no puedes truncar una línea HTML de forma arbitraría basándote en tu pantalla. Cuando alguien intente ver esa misma página en un iPhone 2, el contenido se verá horrible. En cuanto a las otras dudas o cualquier duda futura, tienes que plantearlas basándote en problemas concretos. Como consejo te digo que aquí las prisas no son buenas, hay mucho ánimo de ayudar, pero preguntas así sin nada concreto no se adaptan al formato del sitio.

Comment: Revisa cómo crear y manejar los elementos DIV, ese tipo de elementos sirven para situar contenido dentro de ellos y que no moleste al resto del contenido de la página

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esto:

**En tu archivo html**

```
<div class="parrafo-container">
<p class="parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt 
laborum ut, culpa tempora itaque hic velit dolores, corrupti quod vel nobis possimus 
sapiente praesentium nihil maiores reiciendis blanditiis non quidem!</p>
</div>
```

**En tu archivo css**

```
.parrafo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.parrafo {
  width: 50%;
}
```